# Jquery select div from inside div

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a main div with multiple divs inside, and I hover one of those div inside the main div, how do I grab the id of that hovered div ?

CODE here:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1" class="inner"></div>
    <div id="div2" class="inner"></div>
    <div id="div3" class="inner"></div>
    <div id="div4" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#main').on('mouseover', '.inner', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z2WJA/)

```
$("#main >div").hover(function(){
 alert(this.id);

});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".inner").hover(function() {
    alert(this.id);
}
```